# SpringでJSPを使わない

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, thymeleaf

SpringとhibernateのDBアクセスの機能を使ってviewから受け取ったselectで始まるSQL文を実行して表示する簡単なwebアプリを作ってみたいと思っていますが今どきjspは使わないと聞きました。
どうやらThymeleafというのを使うようですが具体的にはどうするのでしょうか？
私はSpring bootの知識はなくSpring web MVCの初歩的知識はあります。
form:やspring:タグは使えないと思いますがどのようにアプローチしますか。
Spring MVCは忘れてSpring bootを勉強し直したほうがいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVCのアプリがあるのであれば、以下のような手順でJSPをThymeleafに移行できたと思います。

1. `pom.xm`(Mavenを使っている場合)に、`thymeleaf-spring`の`dependency`を追加する（以下は例）

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
       <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Spring MVCのBean定義xmlにThymeleafと連携するための設定を追加する

   ```
   <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
     <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
     <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
     <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
     <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
   </bean>
   <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
     <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
     <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
   </bean>
   ```
3. JSPの代わりになるHTMLファイルをつくって動作確認する（JSP(JSTL)の`c:out`をThymeleafの`th:text`に変更するような修正が必要になります。ControllerはJSP用のものをそのまま使えるはずです）

   /WEB-INF/templates/test.html

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
     <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
       <title>Thymeleaf</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <span th:text="${test}"></span>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```

   TestController.java

   ```
   @Controller
   public class TestController {
       @RequestMapping(value = "", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
       public String test(Model model) {
           model.addAttribute("Test", "Test Thymeleaf!!");
           return "test";
       }
   }
   ```

※動作確認をしていないので、細かい部分で間違いはあるかもしれませんが、この程度の変更でよかったはずです。

JSPを理解している人であれば、Thymeleafは難しくないと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございますイメージ掴めました。

Answer (score 0):

> 今どきjspは使わないと聞きました。

Spring BootでJSP利用を避けるべきだというのは[リファレンスにもあります](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines)が、理由はJSPを用いる場合には[いくつかの制約](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations)が発生するためです。
(主観になりますが、JSPとThymeleafの「今どき」具合は同程度だと思います。)

> Spring MVCは忘れてSpring bootを勉強し直したほうがいいでしょうか？

Spring Bootで用いられているのはSpring MVCそのものです。
Spring MVCの知識はそのまま活用できます。

具体的な実装手順が知りたい、という点については、オフィシャルのガイド
https://spring.io/guides
で検索してみるのが一つの手段かと思います。
例えばThymeleafであれば

- [Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

JDBCであれば

- [Accessing Relational Data using JDBC with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/)

があり、それぞれ簡潔なサンプルコードも付随しています。